# Show PDF in a Vaadin View

Tags: pdf, vaadin, vaadin7

I want to show a PDF in a Vaadin view. I create a BrowserFrame and I pass the StreamResource of the PDF:

```
StreamResource streamResource = new StreamResource(
                getPresenter().createPdfStreamSource(), report.getName() + ".pdf");


BrowserFrame pdf = new BrowserFrame(null, streamResource);
pdf.setSizeFull();

content.addComponent(pdf);
```

This code creates an iframe with the following source:

```
http://localhost:8080/my-app/vaadinServlet/APP/connector/0/134/source/mypdf.pdf
```

If I point the browser to this URL, it shows the PDF properly. However in my application the PDF view doesn't show. What am I doing wrong?

I am testing this in Google Chrome.

**Edit**: I downloaded the plugin PDF Viewer based on PDF.js and my app works fine. Does the Chrome PDF reader plugin need special configuration?

Comment: Could you show the source of `getPresenter().createPdfStreamSource()`?

Comment: Maybe have a look at [this](https://vaadin.com/docs/-/part/framework/components/components-embedded.html) part of the book... It's about embedding resources in your UI - Maybe you are just using the wrong components.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An `iframe` is probably not the best option to render a PDF, especially on mobile browsers. Check the [WT PDF Viewer](https://vaadin.com/directory/component/wt-pdf-viewer) add-on which is based on pdf.js for a more compatible solution.